# Cant read an AppEngine ndb model by it's id

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have the following code to insert, then read an entity back, by key. However I always get None back. I could swear this is the way I have done it before in older versions of AppEngine...

```
    guid = uuid.uuid1().hex

    a = User(id=guid)
    a.email = "a"
    a.username = "a"
    a.put()

    logging.info("a.key: %s", a.key)

    theKey = ndb.Key(User, guid)

    entity1 = theKey.get()          #doesnt work
    entity2 = User.get_by_id(guid)  #doesnt work

    logging.info("guid: %s", guid)
    logging.info("key: %s", keyValue)
    logging.info("entities: %s %s" % (entity1, entity2))
```

Comment: You're logging keyValue, which you haven't defined. Fixing that, and definite a User model with email and username properties, the code runs fine and returns entities in both cases. Is this your actual code?

Comment: @Greg - You're right, I just checked my model class and I had: id = ndb.StringProperty() - which shouldn't of been there...it all works fine now...very embarrassed :-/

Comment: `guid` must be a string `str(guid)`